# Search function! JS API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, jsp, razor-2

There's a company that has a local website that provides a list of job search opportunities.

The website is something similar to Indeed.com! Here is the link. - 
http://www.akronworks.com/ 
The entire website is in ASP.NET! C#, SQL, HTML, CSS.

Is there a link or a way to use Indeed API? Or a way to find the basic "Search Function Structure Template? I'm creating an application that needs a basic local job search function.

Everything else can be written in the SQL Database.

I found something that was written in Javascript. 
Heres the code -

```
function indeed_clk(a,sig) { var hr = a.href; var si = hr.indexOf('&jsa='); if (si > 0) return; var jsh = hr + '&jsa=' + sig; if ( jsh.indexOf('&inchal') == -1 ) jsh += '&inchal=apiresults'; a.href = jsh; }function init(){(new Image()).src=document.location.protocol+'//gdc.indeed.com/rpc/apilog?a=apiresults';}if (window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener('load', init, false);}else if (window.attachEvent){window.attachEvent('onload', init);}
```

I found this inside of there source-code. I'm wondering how all of the positions get displayed. How many databases do you think you this site would take to operate? All of the positions have to be store in multiple databases right?

Is there any open-source code that could provide the same functionality?

Thanks - Blake

Answer (score 0):

Indeed does have an api you can use their site link (you will need to create a developer account): 
http://www.indeed.com/jsp/apiinfo.jsp

and additional info, how to's, etc. you can go to:
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/indeed